# How to make SchemaCrawler work in Windows?

Tags: postgresql, database-diagram, schemacrawler

How to make SchemaCrawler to work in Windows?

GraphViz is installed. Now I'm trying to make a diagram of a whole PostgreSQL database using the command line:

```
sc.cmd -command graph -outputformat png \
    -outputfile=graph.png -database=my_database \
    -user=the_user -password=my_password -infolevel=standard
```

but am getting an error about `lib.jakarta-httpcore-nio-4.0-alpha4.jar` which could not be found:

> Fehler: Hauptklasse lib.jakarta-httpcore-nio-4.0-alpha4.jar konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden

Answer (score 1):

SchemaCrawler has no direct links to jars outside of the JDK, other than the database driver. Try downloading the latest [SchemaCrawler for PostgreSQL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/schemacrawler/files/SchemaCrawler%20-%20PostgreSQL/9.1/) zip file, which comes bundled with the open source PostgreSQL driver. The following jars are in that download: jakarta-httpcore-nio-4.0-alpha4.jar and postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar.

Another thing to try is to not use sc.cmd - that is, replacing:

```
sc.cmd .....
```

with

```
java -classpath lib/* schemacrawler.tools.postgresql.Main .....
```

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler

Comment: The link you suggested leads exactly to the archive I have downloaded and I have problems with. If I replace sc.cmd with java -classpath the error is the same. I am not familiar with Java. I just want to run the tool and get the diagram.

Comment: Paul, please download version 9.2: http://sourceforge.net/projects/schemacrawler/files/SchemaCrawler%20-%20IBM%20DB2/9.2/

Comment: Oh, yeah! One step forward. Thank you. But now I'm getting the error: schemacrawler.schemacrawler.SchemaCrawlerSQLException: Could not connect to jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:5432/mydatabase, with properties {user=myuser}. All the credentials are valid; I can connect to PostgreSQL from pgAdmin.